# How to use enum in a Postgres database in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, enums, database-migration

PostgreSQL has the concept of [enumerated types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-enum.html) built into the database.

How would you implement a table with a column that uses an enumerated type in Rails 3? Do you need to define the enum in PostgreSQL somehow? How could you create a DB migration that does this?

Working in Rails 3.07, Ruby 1.92p180, PostgreSQL 8.3.

Comment: What exactly prevents you from adding this enum in Postgresql through a migration, and from using it afterwards?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rails does not support the `ENUM` datatype out of the box. This is because not all databases support it that datatype. I found that a common way of dealing with `ENUM` values is to manually create the enum column in your database (PostgreSQL in your case), and deal with it as a `string` column in your Rails application. Then, use the [validates_inclusion_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_inclusion_of) validator to force the use of the allowed values.

```
validates_inclusion_of :gender, :in => [ "male", "female" ]
```

And use native SQL in your migration to add the enum field:

```
class AddEnumType < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute ".." # your native PostgreSQL queries to add the ENUM field
  end
end
```

**edit (June 2014)**

Rails 4.1 now [supports enums](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#active-record-enums). The `validates_inclusion_of` can now be changed to:

```
enum gender: [ :male, :female ]
```

(However, this is still not natively supported by the underlying database, so the native SQL migration is still needed.)

Comment: This means you cannot ever do a schema:load though, since it breaks shema.rb. For mysql, there are the rubygem-enum_column3 gem. Dunno how hard it would be to modify that to work for postgres as well..

Comment: Thanks for that info. I hardly ever use `ENUM`s or `schema:load` ;)

Comment: You don't have any tests? That use schema:load. Your test database enums will end up as strings instead.

Comment: Of course I have tests. Didn't realize `schema:load` is used there, thanks. It would be nice to have native enum-support in ActiveRecord one day.

Comment: Tests use `db:test:prepare`, which clones the development DB. It doesn't care about `schema:load`.

Comment: false. db:test:prepare checks for pending migrations and loads the schema from db/schema.rb

Comment: Wow, after all this time it is great to see this feature has been created!

Comment: Important note on your edit that "Rails 4.1 now supports enums": The new functionality you linked has nothing to do with the PostgreSQL ENUM type. It simply establishes a mapping between String/Symbol values (used in the Ruby classes) and corresponding Fixnum values, stored in the database in an integer column.

Comment: @mercurial Hence my remark "this is still not natively supported by the underlying database".

Answer (score 9):

You can also set schema to use raw SQL instead of a .rb file.  If you're leveraging more advanced features of a database (enums, full text search, triggers, functions, etc) rather than simply using it as a generic datastore this will make your life easier.

Just set this line in your config/application.rb

```
# Use SQL for the schema due to many database specific settings
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

It will output a structure.sql file that will solve that problem for you.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above answers, for Rails 4 (and possibly 3.2) you can do this to avoid "Invalid OID" type warnings:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::OID.alias_type 'my_enum_type', 'text'
```

When querying, you will also want to convert the string to your type, for example

```
scope :my_enum_value_is, ->(value){ 
  where('my_enum_value = ?::my_enum_type', value) 
}
```

You'll also want to patch the column parser:

```
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column
  private
  def simplified_type_with_my_enum_type(field_type)
    if field_type == 'my_enum_type'
      field_type.to_sym
    else
      simplified_type_without_my_enum_type(field_type)
    end
  end
  alias_method_chain :simplified_type, :my_enum_type
end
```

Comment: Very interesting. Moreover, it would be awesome to have a way for ActiveRecord to automatically append the `::my_enum` casting to specific constants.

Comment: @rewritten It is possible to have rails convert it automatically, see point type from https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7324 for reference. If you'd like to submit a PR to rails I'll be glad to help (will also need schema.rb support to make it into master).

Comment: I think that is for specific types, do you propose to have some code to manage arbitrary user-defined types or just enums? Let's continue this by twitter, just followed you...